# Cannot align input and button with Angular

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I am having some trouble aligning an input and button on the same line. I am new to using Angular-Material, but I cannot seem to find any documentation or forums explaining how to solve my issue.

I was able to make it work by having the md-button sit outside of the form and flex, but this stops the natural functionality of hitting enter and submitting.

**This is how it looks:**

[image]

**This is how I want it to look:**

[image]

How could I correctly do this with Angular-Material?

**HTML**

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="center center">
  <div class="bannerCenter" flex-sm="90" flex-gt-sm="60">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="center end" style="height: 100px;">
      <h1><span class="icon-bunny-logo text-purple logo-large"></span><span class="icon-text-logo text-black logo-text-large"></span></h1>
    </div>
    <md-content class="text-black md-content-transparent" flex layout-padding>
      <p class="banner-text banner-text-top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet sagittis sapien. Quisque et tincidunt orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam luctus leo sit amet aliquet tincidunt. Donec nec elementum nunc. Nam ut pretium elit. Mauris mollis et neque eu rutrum.</p>
      <p class="banner-text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet sagittis sapien. Quisque et tincidunt orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam luctus leo sit amet aliquet tincidunt. Donec nec elementum nunc. Nam ut pretium elit. Mauris mollis et neque eu rutrum.
      </p>
      <p class="banner-text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent sit amet sagittis sapien. Quisque et tincidunt orci. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam luctus leo sit amet aliquet tincidunt. Donec nec elementum nunc. Nam ut pretium elit. Mauris mollis et neque eu rutrum.
      </p>
    </md-content>

    <div class="banner-text-top" layout="row" layout-align="center center" layout-wrap>
      <div flex="65">
          <form name="subscriptionForm">
            <md-input-container class="md-block">
              <label class="text-black">Email Address</label>
              <input class="bigClass text-black" ng-model="something.email" type="email" ng-required="true">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised" ng-click="something.save(newSomething); newSomething='';">Submit</md-button>
          </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the solution, let me come Back Home And if no answer are give  I will post mine.

Answer (score 4):

The problem lies in the fact that you're using the `md-block` class in your `md-input-container`.

Here's a working pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoRxGP

Best!

Comment: No that did not solve the issue. I still have the same effect as before.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
md-input-container .md-error-spacer{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I ended up solving the issue myself. I basically started over and referred to the [Material-Angular documentation demonstrating inputs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/input). This is how I ended up fixing this:

**HTML**

```
<form name="subscriptionForm">
  <div layout layout-align="center center">
    <div layout layout-align="center center" layout-sm="column" flex="65">
      <md-input-container flex>
        <label class="text-black">Email Address</label>
        <input class="text-black" ng-model="newSomething.email" type="email">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-button layout="column" class="md-raised" ng-click="something.save(newRSomething); newSomething='';">Submit</md-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[image]

Comment: that is exactly what @Maurizio Vacca said to you!

Comment: @Gianmarco no not exactly! Lol The outcome looks the same, but Maurizio Vacca's answer did not seem to work in the code i have already.